# Processing php code after readfile() - can an iframe work?

Tags: php, iframe, header, readfile

** Update - I knew it should work. I fixed the iframe code to only echo the parameters instead of the whole line. Somehow this fixed it. Now I can download a file asynchronously and continue processing in the current php **

I'm trying to wrap my head around processing of headers and readfile(). It appears that no code is executed after readfile() is called. I presume because of the "One HTTP Request, one file" rule.

I read a suggestion of using an iframe to perhaps get around this limitation. I've tried putting this function in a separate file (e.g. writezip) and calling it from a another file like:

```
<!-- this code works and allows for an invisible file transfer-->
<iframe src="<? echo 'writezip.php' ?>" height="0px" width="0px" frameBorder="0" id="getfileurl"> </iframe>

<!-- this code does not and will not run the iframe asynchronously -->
<!-- Remove this line for a working solution -->
<? echo '<iframe src="Untitled-1.php">' ?>

<? echo "File was sent to you"; ?>
```

But this doesn't appear to work (I removed the function declaration when it is in its own file - so it will execute when the file loads). Any suggestions? How would you display a message saying "A file was sent" - Thanks in advance

```
<?php
function writezip(){
    $fullfilename = "post.zip";
    $outfilename = "test.zip";
    $mode = "download";

    if (file_exists($fullfilename)){
        // Parse Info / Get Extension
        $fsize = filesize($fullfilename);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullfilename);
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

        // Determine Content Type
        switch ($ext) {
            case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
            case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
            case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
            case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
            case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
            case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
            case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
            case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
            case "jpeg":
            case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;

            default: $ctype="application/force-download";
        }

        header("Pragma: public"); // required
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
        header("Content-Type: $ctype");

        $outfilename = ($outfilename=="" ? basename($fullfilename) : $outfilename);
        if ($mode == "view"){
            // View file
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$outfilename);
        } 
        else {
            // Download file
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($outfilename));
        }

        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);

        if (ob_get_length() > 0 ) {
            ob_clean();
            flush();
        }
        readfile( $fullfilename );
        die("anything here");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "File not found: ". $fullfilename;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my original  code:

```
<? echo '<iframe src="Untitled-1.php">' ?>
```

did not work for some reason. The updated code in the original works.